# group by rows to get the distinct row using filter in admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

Thanks in advance, I wanted to know is it possible to get distinct rows from db using the filter in admin-on-rest.example, for example, I want to show a list of distinct offers running but in my database, I have the duplicate offer, is it possible using filter component in admin on rest.

Comment: Can you please tell where have you used reactjs here ? Also post code you have worked on.

Comment: Isn't it the responsability of your backend to send only distinct rows ? I fail to see what react-admin can do here